# Can I reference a table made with table1 in RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I am using the `table1::table1()` function to make the table I want in my paper but I can't see how to reference the table throughout the paper.  Is there a way to reference a table made with table1() using syntax like: `\@ref(tab:x)` in R Markdown?

Comment: Have you tried setting a caption?  That's how `knitr::kable` does it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Caption and label do not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but it's a bit tricky.

The issue is that the `table1` package doesn't support labels in the form that Pandoc is looking for, so you need to put them in by hand.
However, `table1` marks its output in a way that tells Pandoc to ignore the additions you have to make.  So you have to do two workarounds in the following:

- Add a caption to the table using the `caption` argument to `table1()`.
- At the beginning of the caption, include special code like `(\\#tab:thetablename)`, where you replace `thetablename` with a
  unique string of your own choice.
- Wrap the call to the `table1()` function in `knitr::asis_output()`.

Using one of the examples from the `?table1` help page,

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(table1)
dat <- expand.grid(id=1:10, sex=c("Male", "Female"), treat=c("Treated", "Placebo"))
dat$age <- runif(nrow(dat), 10, 50)
dat$age[3] <- NA  # Add a missing value
dat$wt <- exp(rnorm(nrow(dat), log(70), 0.2))

label(dat$sex) <- "Sex"
label(dat$age) <- "Age"
label(dat$treat) <- "Treatment Group"
label(dat$wt) <- "Weight"

units(dat$age) <- "years"
units(dat$wt) <- "kg"
knitr::asis_output(table1(~ sex + age + wt | treat, data=dat,
                          caption = "(\\#tab:thetab)The caption"))
```
````

where the last statement contains both modifications.  This produces
output (using `bookdown::html_document2` format) that looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

and I could refer to the table by number using `\@ref(tab:thetab)` in other parts of the text.

Comment: Thank you so much user2554330.  If you make it to Miami dinner is on me.